# Output/the next command prompt overwrites long command in R

Tags: r, readline

I'm seeing a very strange issue with R (v 3.3.2, running on the command line of a CentOS 7 linux box).  If I execute a command that goes over one line in the terminal, the output appears at the beginning of the second line of the command.  This didn't happen with previous versions of R, though it does happen with later versions I've installed.  I am using Putty as the terminal, but it also happens if I use xterm.

To describe it better, it looks like this:

```
> tmpvaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal=1 [before hitting enter]
> tmpvaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal=1 [after enter, typing overwrites the a's now]
```

If the multiline command outputs something, that output occurs on the second line and overwrites the a's.  If there is an error, then the error message terminates properly and the next prompt follows the error message.  So does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Update: After some more experimenting, I've found another odd behavior.  If I use CTRL-R to search for a previous multiline command, and then execute it, the output or subsequent prompt appears at the same location in the command as where the cursor was.  Here's another example:

```
(reverse-i-search)`1':tmpvaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal=1[cursor on one before hitting enter]
[hit enter and then:]
>tmpvaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaal=1
aaaaaaaaal=>
```

Pretty strange.  Hard to describe so its hard to find any evidence of other problems like this on stack-exchange or elsewhere.  My feeling is it has to do with the readline library but it is strange because this doesn't happen in the shell command line, only in R as far as I can tell.

Update 2:  I've found a potentially more revealing way to replicate this issue.  If you manually add a bunch of newlines (by jamming CTRL-V CTRL-J repeatedly), then hit enter, the next prompt jumps right back up to underneath the last one.  This is not what happens in the underlying shell (bash for me), or in previous versions of R that I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have the answer out there in case anyone else has this issue, the problem was that my system was using an old version of the readline library, 6.2, and the issue disappeared when updating it to the current version, 7.0.  So it would seem that even though later versions of R will install with the outdated readline, they don't exactly work correctly.